# How to make sure a global constructor is called after all static object initializations (DllMain equivalent)?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to make a C++ library, and I need to call a function at load time to initialize it. I am using GCC, so I tried to use `__attribute__((constructor))`, and the function is actually called at load time.

But the aforementioned function makes use of static objects that are in different translation units, so it is unspecified whether those static objects in these translation units are initialized when I need to use them. So, for example, if I want to use std::cout inside this function, I’m boned.

The following code snippet demonstrates the problem pretty well:

```
#include <iostream>

void __attribute__((constructor)) init()
{
    std::cout << "Test\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the function init() will be called at load-time, but it is unspecified whether std::cout is initialized at the moment, and you may well get an error when trying to execute the 5th line.

So my question is, is it possible to make sure the initialization function I need to call at load time will be executed after all static objects are constructed ?

Edit: I forgot to mention this library will be used by preloading it inside another program using the LD_PRELOAD environment variable in order to intercept certain calls, so I can’t ask an user to call a lib_init() function inside his main().

Comment: Not unless you put it inside the `dllmain` or `main`.

Comment: Problem is, I am making a library, so I can’t use main, and I am using GCC, so I can’t use dllmain either. I don’t want to believe this would be a MSVC-specific feature.

Comment: If you do this just for testing, it might be better to write to a logfile which you open yourself. On the other hand you might make your own object which the user should put in his/her main function that initializes your library.

Comment: You can't use a static storage duration object? Then do the initialization in its constructor.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: I would normally have done in that way, but in this case I preload my library in a program using LD_PRELOAD in order to intercept certain calls performed by the said program, so I can’t do that. I’ll update my question with these precisions.

Comment: You *can* (and should) use main. The users of the library have to call the initialization code.

Comment: @Loki Astari: I don’t think this will solve the problem: objects in different translation units could still be uninitialized.

Comment: Don't touch compiler-specific stuff if you can help it. Use proper singleton objects so that their initialization is guaranteed to happen in the right order.

Comment: std::cout is special and has some guarantees I believe. And accessing objects in other translation units you should be using function static member variables to guarantee the order of initialization. But that is not quite your question. You need to put more details into the question of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If this will be a library for 3rd-party usage, I'd strongly insist to require manual call of such "init" function as a part of usage contract. Otherwise, your users may find them in very unpleasant situation they're pinned down by stright-line behavior of your lib.

As an evidence, there is WinSock example: before you call WSAStartup(), nothing is assumed to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention this library will be injected inside some other program with LD_PRELOAD, so unfortunately I can’t ask an user to call an initialization function inside his main function.